Optimization of updating table cells in the database with pewwee python
I'm using the python version 3.12.0
The problem is that updating the data is very slow in this way. It is much more efficient to write all the data from the table into an array of dictionaries, and then recreate the table.
class Pattern(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db
class Parent(Pattern):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'name'
        order_by = ('position', 'id')
    position = IntegerField()
    file_name = CharField(max_length=1000)
    designation = CharField(max_length=1000)
    name = CharField(max_length=1000)
    work_piece = CharField(max_length=1000)
    material = CharField(max_length=1000)
    device_count = CharField(max_length=1000)
    warehouse_count = CharField(max_length=1000)
    prepared_count = IntegerField()
    buy_link = CharField(max_length=1000)
    comment = CharField(max_length=1000)
    is_ordered = IntegerField()
    date_of_receipt = CharField()

for i in Parent.select():
    i.warehouse_count = str(int(i.warehouse_count) + int(i.device_count))
    i.prepared_count += 1
    i.save(only=[Parent.warehouse_count, Parent.prepared_count])

This is an example of table re-creation.
mas = ['position', 'file_name', 'designation', 'name', 'work_piece', 'material', 'device_count', \
       'warehouse_count', 'prepared_count', 'buy_link', 'comment', 'is_ordered', 'date_of_receipt']
dict_array = []
for i in Parent.select():
    dictionary = {}
    data = [i.position, i.file_name, i.designation, i.name, i.work_piece, i.material, \
                                i.device_count, i.warehouse_count, i.prepared_count, i.buy_link, \
                                i.comment, i.is_ordered, i.date_of_receipt]
    for j in range(len(mas)):
        dictionary[mas[j]] = data[j]
    dict_array.append(dictionary)
Parent1.insert_many(dict_array).execute()

But I don't like this approach at all.
